# "done() called multiple times" error with restler when testing with mocha

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm getting a done() called multiple times error when I'm testing a restler call.  It doesn't error if I only make the restler call onece, however it errors if I call the same method twice in one test run.

Here is the simplified version of the test

```
myModule = require 'myModule'

describe 'foo', ->
    describe 'bar', ->
        it "should hi", (done) ->
            myModule.hi done
        it "should hi again", (done) ->
            myModule.hi done
```

and here is myModule

```
rest = require 'restler'
exports.hi = (done) ->

    rest.get('http://google.com'
    ).on "complete", (data, response) ->
      console.log 'getting called once'             
      done null, data
```

Should I be worried about async multiple requests with restler?  What is causing this error?

console log output when I add

```
  ◦ should hi: getting called once
  ✓ should hi (221ms)
  ◦ should hi again: getting called once
  1) should hi
 getting called once
  ✓ should hi again (211ms)
```

Comment: Looks OK at first glance to me. Can you add a `console.log` in your "complete" handler and make sure that is only getting called 2 total times (once per "hi" call)?

Comment: It seems to be getting called more than two times, not sure why, here's the output       ◦ should hi: getting called once
      ✓ should hi (221ms)
      ◦ should hi again: getting called once
      1) should hi
getting called once
      ✓ should hi again (211ms)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an issue with Restler not being updated to be compatible with node 0.10.x

https://github.com/danwrong/restler/pull/113/files

Restler will call the callback multiple times, but there is a pull request that fixes the issue.